# Summary value of calendar object

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I recognized that the return of CalendarList has changed. the summary value was person's name but now it returns email address.

my question is how can I get calendar name using calendar API?

tested url: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list

◆ Before

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#calendarList",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "calendar#calendarListEntry",
   "etag": "\"1578551131788000\"",
   "id": "test@test.com",
   "summary": "Test Calendar", // <-- calendar's name
   "timeZone": "Asia/Tokyo",
```

◆Now

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#calendarList",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "calendar#calendarListEntry",
   "etag": "\"1578551131788000\"",
   "id": "test@test.com",
   "summary": "test@test.com", // <-- email address
   "timeZone": "Asia/Tokyo",
```

Comment: have you tried doing a calendar.get?

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks for your comment. Yes I've tried, and I got same result as list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently a bug in Google calendar. its not returning the title in the summary as it is documented to do [Bug report can be found here.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147386017)

Calendar.get on my primary calendar returns

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#calendar",
 "etag": "\"KfTgGrEyu1otuO_8YfN8ka6X3tg\"",
 "id": "xxx@gmail.com",
 "summary": "xxxx@gmail.com",
 "description": "test",
 "timeZone": "Europe/Copenhagen",
 "conferenceProperties": {
  "allowedConferenceSolutionTypes": [
   "eventHangout"
  ]
 }
}
```

The documentation states that a calendar resource should return

> summary        =  Title of the calendar.

[image]

Comment: add your comment to the bug report you will be notified when its fixed.